# MYSQL - ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have some records like this

```
id  name    sequence
------------------------
1   steve   3
2   lee     2
3   lisa    1
4   john    0
5   smith   0
```

I want to display records like following

```
id  name
------------
1   lisa
2   lee
3   steve
4   john
5   smith
```

When i am using order by clause then it display like

```
name
----
john
smith
lisa
lee
steve
```

### **Query**

```
SELECT name from tbl1 where 1 ORDER BY sequence ASC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT name
FROM tbl1 
ORDER BY sequence = 0,
         sequence ASC
```

or

```
SELECT name
FROM tbl1 
ORDER BY case when sequence <> 0 then 1 else 2 end,
         sequence ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use query with if condition in `ORDER BY` clause

```
SELECT
  name
from tbl1
ORDER BY IF(sequence = 0,name,sequence) ASC
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0b52/1)

Output

```
|  NAME |
|-------|
|  lisa |
|   lee |
| steve |
|  john |
| smith |
```